# random image; without repeating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

First off I'm not very familiar with javascript, thus here I am. 
I have this code for my site to draw a random image. Working from this, how can I make the images not repeat? Thanks in adv! Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

var banner_list = ['http://i1233.photobucket.com/albums/ff389/lxluigixl/Cargo/LM_LogoMark4-4-2.gif',   'http://i1233.photobucket.com/albums/ff389/lxluigixl/Cargo/logobg_dome.png',  'http://i1233.photobucket.com/albums/ff389/lxluigixl/Cargo/logobg_brain.png'];    $(document).ready(function() { var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*banner_list.length);
$(".logobg img").attr(banner_list[ran]);
});  $(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", function(e, pid){
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*banner_list.length);
$(".logobg img").attr("src", banner_list[ran]);
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you display the image splice it out of the array, you can use [`banner_list.splice(ran, 1)`;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). The arguments are `.splice(index, howManyToRemove, howManyToInsert)`. Inserting is optional, so you can just use splice to start at the index of the image you're displaying and remove one. Make sure not to remove it until you're done referencing it.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Although I'm really in need for someone with time to write the piece of code for me. I'm not that java-savvy. I've been trying to figure this out for days now, to no avail.

Comment: That is the code. `banner_list.splice(ran, 1);` Put that right after you're done using the image via the array, which in your example is right after you set the src of the image. Also Java is extremely different from Javascript, for future reference.

Comment: Oh wow thanks a lot robert. I'm a graphic designer, and as you can see I'm quite ignorant when it comes to programming. Thanks for the clarifications ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.splice() as Robert suggest with 2 Arrays. One for unsused and one for used images. Check my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkutianski/5yNdu/).

```
var images = ["http://www.fowkesauto.com/products_pictures/nutsbolt.jpg",
              "http://i01.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/114511763/Fasteners_Bolts_and_Nuts.jpg",
              "http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/DLeonis/DLeonis0810/DLeonis081000018/3706757-bolts-and-nuts-on-white.jpg",
              "http://static3.depositphotos.com/1003288/173/i/950/depositphotos_1737203-Nuts-and-bolts.jpg"],
    usedImages = [];

setInterval(function () {changeImage();},500);

var changeImage = function () {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (images.length)),
        thisImage = images[index];

        usedImages.push(thisImage);
        images.splice(index, 1);

        if (images.length < 1) {
            images = usedImages.splice(0, usedImages.length);
        }

        $("#image").attr("src", thisImage);
}
```